# how to get session id in java script

Tags: javascript, hash, csrf

Currently I have been asked to prevent the CSRF attach in our web application.
I am new to the web application.

Can any one help me regarding this

Guide line I have been given

An easy way to implement this fix is to have every page rendered with a couple of additional hidden variables.

```
var1 = hmac_sha256(timestamp+session_id, secret)
var2 = timestamp
```

On the backend, you take the timestamp and validate it by creating an hmac of the server side secret with the timestamp.  If valid, and the time has not passed, you can allow the request to continue.  This allows you to set expiration on pages and authenticate their creation so cross site request forgery attacks are mitigated.  It should not be possible to use the same valid token twice.

I have identified the steps to do the same.

1. To generate the session id in java script.
2. To generate the secret key in server side ( servlet).
3. Send the secret key to client from server ( may be in login page).
4. keep the csrf token as hidden by generating through timestamp, seesion id and secret key.

   `var $csrfToken = hmac_sha256($timestamp +$seesionId + $mySecretKey)`
5. Decrypt the same in server side if get the

   `var $stringToHash = request.get('key')`
   `var $isValidToken = hmac_sha256($timestamp +$seesionId  + $mySecrtKey) == request.get('csrfToken')`

then proceed with the request handling in servlet.

Can any one help me with code snippet.

Comment: if you list which server you're using, I'm pretty sure we can point out already existing CSRF frameworks for it. You don't generate CSRF in the client, you generate them at the server.

Comment: If you're sending the server secret to the client, it's not secret any more?

Comment: I am using tomcat server and my web application is using jsp and servlet. All requests are of POST method type. I am using ajax call to send the request to sevlet and servlet is sending back json response to render the dynamic page ( client is using pure.js http://beebole.com/pure/) to render the json response from servlet

Comment: CSRF should only kick in for POSt/PUT/DELETE anyway, so that's good. Tomcat has CSRF built in, have a readup on https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/filter.html

Answer (score 1):

The process we're using is to store the csrf token (generated by the server, that's where it gets generated, not in the client. It's a cross site request forgery prevention mechanism, so the server needs to be able to verify it's a real token, not the client) in a `<meta name="csrf-token" value="...">` element (which is a W3C validating name) and then passing this along as a request header when doing AJAX calls by using jQuery's `beforeSend`:

```
var csrf_token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
...
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ...,
  data: {
    ...
  },
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
  },
  ...
});
```

In this case the server needs the header as `X-CSRF-Token` because we're using nodejs with express, which uses connect, which requires that particular string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.In this case then we have to do server side validation   String csrf_token_request = request.getHeader("X-CSRF-Token");
        if (serverCsrfToken == csrf_token_request){
  continue;
}else{
 return;
}

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're doing CSRF correctly or not may be a discussion for another post.  Your original question was how can you get the Session Id in Javascript.  Session Ids are typically stored as cookies, but are named differently based on the server.  From the Wikipedia page on [Session Id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID).

- JEE = JSESSIONID
- PHP = PHPSESSID
- ASP = ASPSESSIONID

You can then use a library like [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to access the correct cookie and get the session id.